# Select where at least N joined entities exist

Tags: sql-server, performance, entity-framework

Imagine selecting customers who have at least two orders. How can this be expressed using Entity Framework in a performant way?

```
context.Customers.Where(c => c.Orders.Count() > 1)
```

This seemingly innocent expression results in SQL resembling:

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[UserId]) AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Project1]
WHERE [Project1].[C1] > 1
```

Is SQL Server smart enough to avoid calculating the complete count across the join for each entity, or should a different approach be used?

How would I test for this, beyond simply running the query and testing the response times?

Here are some other query expressions that I have considered. Simple tests show little in the way of a performance difference between them.

```
context.Customers.Where(c => c.Orders.Take(2).Count() > 1)

context.Customers.Where(c => c.Orders.OrderBy(o => o.Id).Skip(1).Any())

context.Orders.GroupBy(l => l.Customer).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(g => g.Key)
```

Comment: Why can't you use a `select ... from [tables] group by ... having count(*) > 1` instead of using all the nested sub-queries?

Comment: That's the SQL that's generated by the Entity Framework. I'd like to use the C# side of Entity Framework if I can. I'll include your example at the end of the question. EF doesn't seem to use the `HAVING` keywork in such a case though.

Comment: What query plan is generated by the above (EF-generated) query?  I don't think that we should second-guess SQL Server- it very well might optimize the join.